# jquery change background image on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, background-image

I have several divs that I want to generate css background images for.  They will change on hover.  Yes, I'm aware that I could easily do this in css, but it needs to be done in jquery.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hoverBox').css('background', 'url(img/box' + id + '.jpg)')  
    $('.hoverBox').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'url(img/box' + this.id + '_back.jpg)')                      
    },
    function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'url(img/box' + this.id + '.jpg)')                       
    });
});
```

HTML is like this:

```
<div class="hoverBox" id="benefits">
content</div>
<div class="hoverBox" id="installation">
content</div>
<div class="hoverBox" id="shoponline">
content</div>
```

This should be so easy, but I can't seem to make it work.

Assistance would be much appreciated!  TIA.

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I think this is:  'url(img/box' + id + '.jpg)', but I can't work out where I'm going wrong. The initial background image doesn't show and then of course, the hover image doesn't either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the id?

Is it some mysterious variable defined somewhere else or do you think the id will be read from the selector is some magical way?

I am guessing you want to use each() to get the id.

Comment: Great. Thanks for that - got it working. The sarcasm was unnecessary, but each() was what I needed.

Comment: How about updating your code or adding an example of how you used "each()" to solve the problem? It would be helpful to others (like me ^^) having the same problem.